# drawing routes on ios 6 maps

Tags: ios, mapkit

On iOS 5.1 and before I could use google maps API to get directions:

f.e.:
http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=41.029598,28.972985&daddr=41.033586,28.984546
or another.

But now routes from google does not match roads on iOS 6 (apple) maps.

How can I get routes for iOS 6 (apple) maps and draw them on MKMapOverlayView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple do not have a route generation api. And using data from Google's javascript API on top of Apple's maps is in violation of Google's Ts&Cs :-/